# Smarty error, catchable fatal error

Tags: php, smarty

I recently made a site for someone with Smarty, everything worked like it should. When I had to edit something today (~ 2 weeks after initial release) i deleted the smarty cache to update all pages, now the pages are not generated anymore, it only gives the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to _smarty_template_buffer::append_subtree() must be an instance of _smarty_parsetree, instance of _smarty_text given, called in /home/public_html/classes/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php on line 2167 and defined in /home/public_html/classes/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_parsetree.php on line 268
```

The weird thing is, after some page refreshes it randomly does generate the page without the error. I can't tell why this behaviour is happening.

The PHP version is 5.4.17
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Perhaps because you delete files that Smarty still remember and try to find. You can look at Smarty [caching](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.tpl) and Smarty [compile all templates](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.compile.all.templates.tpl)

Comment: This could be if smarty used a database, but it doesn't. So thats not the case I guess, or am I missing something?

Comment: Smarty will never use a database. It does save some knowledge in files. Just came up with this solution because you mention deleting the cache. Try to delete cache and let Smarty compile all templates